# Don't get any result using Saxon Xpath 2.0

Tags: java, xml, xpath, saxon

I want to parse xml using xpath 2.0 or 3.0 expressions.
I would like to use the most updated version for XPath, so I download Saxon jars.
This is my code:

```
Processor proc = new Processor(false);
DocumentBuilder builder = proc.newDocumentBuilder();
XdmNode doc = builder.build(new File(file.getPath()));
XPathCompiler xpath = proc.newXPathCompiler();
XPathSelector selector = xpath.compile(mappingXPath.get(key)).load();
selector.setContextItem(doc);
for (XdmItem item : selector) {
        XdmNode node = (XdmNode) item;
        org.w3c.dom.Node element = (org.w3c.dom.Node) node.getExternalNode();
        System.out.println(element.getTextContent());
}
```

for example, xpath expression "//mods/identifier[@type="doi"]" for xml:

````
<collection>
  <mods xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3" xmlns:etd="http://www.ntltd.org/standards/metadata/etdms/1.0/etdms.xsd" xmlns:local="http://idea.library.drexel.edu" xmlns:mods="http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3" xmlns:datacite="https://schema.datacite.org/meta/kernel-4.0/metadata.xsd" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <identifier type="assetId">16</identifier>
<identifier type="doi">10.17918/D8VD4T</identifier>
 </mods>
</collection>```

my selector is empty, why I don't get any result while I run the same expression and xml file in https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html
and it provide results?
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`XdmNode.getExternalNode()` will only return a result if the XDM node is a wrapper/view of an external node such as a DOM node. A node built using the Saxon `DocumentBuilder` is a native XDM node, not a view of an external DOM node. If you want to use DOM with Saxon you can - just build the DOM node externally and wrap it using `DocumentBuilder.wrap(domNode)`. But note that Saxon is 5 to 10 times slower when processing DOM nodes than when using its native XDM tree model.

Comment: It's happening before, my selector is empty. it doesn't even get inside the for loop.

Comment: You haven't shown us your XPath expression so it's impossible to tell you why it doesn't select anything. I only pointed out the error I could see, not the errors we can't see.

Comment: Your XML is in a namespace and your XPath ignores the fact. Search SO for "XPath default namespace" to find thousands of other people who have fallen into this trap.

Comment: In your specific context, `xpath.declareNamespace("", "http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3")` should work.

Comment: It worked!!! Thanks a lot! can't believe that the solution was so simple... although I didn't saw this in any of code examples of using saxon, even in their guide it doesn't say to declare the namespace

Comment: It's unfortunate, but there seems to be a real psychological obstacle here. People see that namespace declaration and their eyes skip right past it because it looks like boring officialese small print, and they just write the query as if it wasn't there. Everyone falls into this trap once, and it's very hard to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Mike wrote in his answer, if you have your `XdmNode` `node` and want its string contents, you can use `node.getStringValue()`, that should give the result `getTextContent()` would give you an a DOM node.

The documentation of the method `getStringValue` is at https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation10/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/XdmItem.html#getStringValue--.